# Import MATLAB data (.mat) in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, matlab

I have a file from MATLAB in (.mat) format. I want to import this in GRASS GIS, but I get the following warning.

[image]

Comment: m files contain matlab scripts no data. You can't open them in GRASS.

Answer (score 1):

The .m file is not readable by GRASS: you need to save your data in a .mat file

in matlab (note that I force the use of version 4):

```
save('yourfile.mat','-v4')
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend.
You are right, of course I also meant the .mat format, but I mistyped the .m (as shown in the image above.)
What do you mean by (-v4)? Explain a little.Thanks for your guidance

Comment: by default the mat file will be exported in the latest Matlab version, but the grass tool needs version 4 (an older version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SciPy `scipy.io` to read and write .mat files using the functions `loadmat` and `savemat` in Python. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html